Pumping Lemma for showing that L is not context-free
It is asked to show that the language $L = \{ a^{mn}b^n | m,n \ge 1 \}$ is not context free using pumping lemma. In my opinion we should use $z = a^{(k+1)^2}b^{(k+1)} \in L$ which gives us three cases:

$vx\in a^{(k+1)^2}$: then $z_2 = a^{(k+1)^2 + |vx|}b^{(k+1)} \in L \iff \exists h \ge 0. (k+1)^2 + |vx| = h(k+1) \iff |vx| = (k+1)(h-k-1)$

Since $|vx| > 0$ from pumping lemma's hypothesis, then $h-k-1 > 0 \iff h > k+1$.
But then again $|vx| = (k+1)(h-k-1) \ge k + 1 > k$. So $|vx| > k$ which contradicts $|vwx| \le k$ and $z_2 \notin L$.

$vx \in b^{(k+1)}$: this case is solved similarly to case 1.

I find myself stuck in case 3, where $v\in a^{(k+1)^2}$ and $x \in b^{(k+1)}$:
$z_2 = a^{(k+1)^2 + |v|}b^{(k+1) + |x|} \in L \iff \exists h\ge 0. (k+1)^2 + |v| = h((k+1) + |x|)$ and I cannot go further. Does somebody have any idea on how to show it?
